is there only one node table in ethereum's discovery protocol?
From what I know about the geth source code, there is only one node table in the discover protocol--discv4. That table is located in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/p2p/discover/table.go.
But as I know, there are more than one node table in Bitcoin/Monero. If there is only one node table in the discv4 protocol, why? Why is ethereum different from Bitcoin/Monero?
